# Why can't I use more than levels in a select linq statement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have three tables in my database:

[image]

What I want is to get items from the table wedstrijden like this:

```
int id = 3;
var wedstrijden = from w in db.wedstrijden 
                  where w.teams.teamleden.gebruikersid == id 
                  select w;
```

Unfortunately i get the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1593: Delegate
>   'System.Func' does not take 1
>   arguments

Does anyone have a clue what's causing the error or where i can find the answer to my question?

Comment: You've got a 1..* relationship from `teams` to `teamleden`, so the property `w.teams.teamleden` should be a collection, not a single value.

Comment: Have you included the `System.Linq` namespace?

Comment: for non dutch speakers: teamleden means team members.

Comment: Next time I will create an English scheme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `wedstrijden.teams.teamleden` is an enumerable so you have to check each item individually:

```
int id = 3;
var wedstrijden = from w in db.wedstrijden 
                  where w.teams.teamleden.Any(t => t.gebruikersid == id)
                  select w;
```

Comment: Wrong.  `w.teams` isn't a collection, `w.teams.teamleaden` is a collection.  Look at the `one to many` relationships in the diagram.

Comment: It confused me at first too. :)

Comment: Ah now I also understand pluralization. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Your names are quite misleading because of plural/singular form misuse.

**The problem is`w.teams.teamleden.gebruikersid` makes no sense with this diagram.**

It *looks* like `wedstrijden.teams` means "teams" when in fact it is a single team.
Again, it *looks* like `teams.teamleden` is a single entity when in fact **the relationship is one-to-many**.

Because many `teamleden` entities match a single `teams` entity, you can't put a dot, it's just as meaningless as this:

```
from p in db.Products
where p.Owner.Orders.ID == id // what would you expect this to mean?
select p
```

Comment: I'm guessing the names make more sense in the OP's native language than they do in English.

Comment: Very probably. However, although English is not my native language, I would never write code in Russian and even if I did, I would translate the member names before positing a question on SO.